AWS VpcID not recognized with policy
I try to create a policy for my AWS apigateway. Just allow access to our company gateway IP and to allow the source VPC from the kubernetes cluster.
The gateway IP is working well, but if I try to add the source VPC from the cluster the API deny always. My policy looks like:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:56140AAAAAA:xxxxxx/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "AWS:SourceIp": "18.18.18.18/32"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:56140AAAAAA:xxxxxx/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-123"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

It looks like that the Policy will not get the VpcID from where the call comes from.
To emulate a cluster call I connect to a poh shell inside the cluster and start the curl call to the api.
The result always is:
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1....

Is there anything I use wrong? I expect the source VPC is the VPC from the cluster, isn't it?

For regular IAM policies, the aws:SourceVpc key is included in the request context only if the requester uses a VPC endpoint to make the request.

Per the API Gateway condition keys docs, the aws:SourceVpc key can be used only for private APIs.
